# linear function composition

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all functions mapping the positive integers to the positive integers such that $f^5(x)=kx$ for a positive integer $k$.

My approach to this problem consisted of trying out functions, as I cannot figure out a methodical way to approach such a problem. An example is when I tried functions such as $f(x)=x\sqrt[5]{k}$ and $f(x)=k/x$, these do not give positive integers for all values of $x$.

Comment: I fixed the tags – this isn't [tag:functional-analysis] – please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $k=1$ is relatively straightforward: $f^5(x)=x$, so each positive integer must be either a fixed point or part of a $5$-cycle. So that yields all (finite and infinite) products of disjoint $5$-cycles.

The case $k\gt1$ has an added twist. Imagine the positive integers arranged in towers of the form $rk^i$, one tower for each positive integer $r$ not divisible by $k$. Instead of numbers being connected in cycles, these towers need to be connected in cycles, and every iteration around the cycle needs to go up one step, in a sort of spiral. So you get all admissible functions by forming $5$-cycles from the positive integers not divisible by $k$ and picking a point in each cycle at which you multiply by $k$ (in addition to the cycling operation).

For instance, for $k=3$ you could have a cycle $(4,5,7,1,2)$, with the extra factor of $k$ inserted between $2$ and $4$, leading to the mappings

$$4\to5\to7\to1\to2\to12\to15\to21\to3\to6\to36\to\cdots\;.$$

Comment: I am still confused a bit. For example, what would be the cycle for $k=2022$? And how do you generate the $5$ cycles? Also how is it related to the towers?

Comment: @user1134699: It's not "the" cycle – you need to arrange *all* the towers in cycles; I was just giving an example of one such cycle. You could use the same cycle $(4,5,7,1,2)$ as an example for $k=2022$, since none of those numbers is divisible by $2022$. For $k=2022$, this would lead to the mappings $$4\to5\to7\to1\to2\to8088\to10110\to14154\to2022\to4044\to16353936\to\cdots\;.$$ It's related to the towers in that you cycle through $5$ towers and each time you complete the cycle you need to go "up" one level in the towers by multiplying by $k$. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: So this means that the possible functions would be all $rk^i$. But where does $i$ end? is it an infinite cycle?

Comment: @user1134699: Yes, it's infinite. It has to be. $f^5(x)=kx$, so $f^{10}(x)=f^5\left(f^5(x)\right)=k^2x$ and so on, so starting at $r$ you eventually reach all numbers in the tower $rk^i$.